# Features Stapled to a SharePoint 2013 Team Site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

It is possible (but perhaps no longer best practice) to create a custom web template that extends the SharePoint 2013 team site. However, when applying this approach there are marked differences between the out of the box team site created and the custom site. This is due to the extra features "stapled" to the out of the box team site definition in SharePoint 2013 that do not get fired in the custom template. The solution is to add these feature id's to the custom template.

Is there any easy way to determine which features are stapled to an existing site definition?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the onet.xml file of the particular site definition. You can find it in the 15 hive. The full path of team site one.xml file is `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\sts\xml`